# Silverlight Windows Phone 7: How to add content to a PivotControl?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a pivot control:

```
            PivotItem sectionPivot = new PivotItem()
            {
                Header = sect.Name,
                Content = new StackPanel()
            };
```

How can I add content to it?

**Edit**: The reason I'm doing it programmatically is because I don't know how many pivots there will be or what they will contain until runtime. Is there some way to do that in XAML?

Comment: why aren't you doing it in xaml instead?

Comment: Because I don't know the number of items or their content until runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer from me.  The OP added info to the question that they don't know how many there could be, and if you could still do it in XAML.

Yes, you can.

The `Pivot` control has an `ItemsSource` property, and you could bind that to something in your class that is being populated dynamically.

```
<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" ItemsSource="{Binding MyPivotItemsSource}" />
```

Each item in that source would end up as a pivotitem.  You'd also have to set up templates and stuff, so its still a lot of work...

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to do it all programatically, just add stuff to the stack panel you just created.

```
        var panel = new StackPanel();
        panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Hello" });

        PivotItem sectionPivot = new PivotItem()
        {
            Header = sect.Name,
            Content = panel;
        };
```

I typed all that without doing any checking, but hypothetically that should work...

Comment: This should work, but if I had a choice I'd try to write it in xaml first... just sayin'

Comment: @nate very true.  thats why i prefaced mine with "if you're going to do it programatically..." :)